# How to design and implement a form which contains a mask (similar to bitmask, but non-binary)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing an app using Reactjs and Material-UI. I need the user to enter a mask of specified length that contains of several letters, e.g. I, V and C. I'm looking for some design pattern or solution for this kind of a problem.
Here's what I've been thinking of:

- In other app I've seen a series of text fields, each of them containing a single letter, like this:

[image: Idea no. 1]

It would be great, because it shows how many positions there are, it's perfectly readable and I could even add indices in helper texts of the text fields to improve user experience even further, but I can't figure out how to move caret from one field to another and without this feature it would be a pain to use.

- My other idea is to initially fill a text field with underscores or dots which would signal to the user how many positions there are to fill. The caret would be initially positioned at the beginning. And when the user would input a letter I would replace an underscore with that letter.

But this solution is not so elegant. Also I would have to program it myself and because there are several different cases to handle (user moving the caret or deleting a letter or inserting a letter between previously entered letters) it would be prone to errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to move caret from one field to another and without this feature it would be a pain to use.

If you attach a `ref` to each of the inputs, your `onChange` function can use this to move the focus to the next input element, by calling `focus()` on that input fields ref.

CodeSandbox demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-65129571-x9er7?file=/index.js. It's not optimized, and there are probably smarter ways of generating the refs and the fields, but perhaps it can be the start of a solution?